# Декодирование URL с обратным слешем

Tags: url, кодировка, r

Всем привет!

Необходимо получить URL адреса на все посты сайта Reddit, согласно поисковому запросу. Для этого использую функцию reddit_urls(), из R-пакета "RedditExtratoR".

Моя проблема.
Некоторые ссылки содержат символы на испанском языке (например 'ó'), которые R-функция возвращает мне в специфической кодировке с обратным слешем ('\').

Например.
Ссылка в браузере: [https://www.reddit.com/r/Barca/comments/4g4fmp/match_thread_fc_barcelona_vs_sporting_de_gijón/](https://www.reddit.com/r/Barca/comments/4g4fmp/match_thread_fc_barcelona_vs_sporting_de_gij%C3%B3n/)

Ссылка, которую мне возращает функция reddit_urls(): "http://www.reddit.com/r/Barca/comments/4g4fmp/match_thread_fc_barcelona_vs_sporting_de_gij\363n/"

В результате R неспособен работать с таким адресом дальше:

```
    > reddit_content('http://www.reddit.com/r/Barca/comments/4g4fmp/match_thread_fc_barcelona_vs_sporting_de_gij\363n/')

Warning messages:
1: In grepl("^https?://(.*)", URL[i]) :
  input string 1 is invalid in this locale
2: In file(con, "r") : cannot open URL 'https://www.reddit.com/r/Barca/comments/4g4fmp/match_thread_fc_barcelona_vs_sporting_de_gij������n/.json?limit=500': HTTP status was '503 Service Unavailable'
3: In file(con, "r") : cannot open URL 'https://www.reddit.com/r/Barca/comments/4g4fmp/match_thread_fc_barcelona_vs_sporting_de_gij������n/.json?limit=500': HTTP status was '503 Service Unavailable'
```

Мне необходимо перекодировать часть URL адреса с обратным слешем "\363n" на символ, который востановит работоспособность ссылки для дальнейшей обработки в R.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте функцию `url_encode` из пакета `urltools`. Символы в URL похоже не в UTF-8 кодировке.

```
url <- "http://www.reddit.com/r/Barca/comments/4g4fmp/match_thread_fc_barcelona_vs_sporting_de_gij\363n/"
cat(url)
http://www.reddit.com/r/Barca/comments/4g4fmp/match_thread_fc_barcelona_vs_sporting_de_gij�n/
cat(urltools::url_encode(url))
http://www.reddit.com/r%2fBarca%2fcomments%2f4g4fmp%2fmatch_thread_fc_barcelona_vs_sporting_de_gij%f3n%2f
cat(iconv(url, "cp1252", "utf8"))
http://www.reddit.com/r/Barca/comments/4g4fmp/match_thread_fc_barcelona_vs_sporting_de_gijón/
cat(urltools::url_encode(iconv(url, "cp1252", "utf8")))
http://www.reddit.com/r%2fBarca%2fcomments%2f4g4fmp%2fmatch_thread_fc_barcelona_vs_sporting_de_gij%c3%b3n%2f
```

Answer (score 0):

Благодарю за помощь!
Выяснилось, что проблема распространена среди Unix-подобных систем.
Нашел решение с помощью iconv() функции здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503143/generating-extended-ascii-in-r-on-a-linux-platform